# Fragment function seems properly written but Metal complains

Tags: metal, metalanguage

**TL;DR: Metal doesn't seem to detect what my vertex shader returns**

I have these two functions written in MSL :

```
vertex float4 base_image_rect(constant float4 *pos [[buffer(0)]],
                                           uint vid [[vertex_id]]) {
    return pos[vid];
}

fragment float4 fragment_image_display(float4 vPos [[stage_in]],
                              texture2d<float, access::sample> imageToRender [[texture(0)]],
                              sampler imageSampler [[sampler(0)]]) {
    return imageToRender.sample(imageSampler, float2(vPos.x, vPos.y));
}
```

When I try to create my render pipeline state with those, using this code:

```
// Make image display render pipeline state
let imageDisplayStateDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
imageDisplayStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = view.colorPixelFormat
imageDisplayStateDescriptor.vertexFunction = library.makeFunction(name: "base_image_rect")
imageDisplayStateDescriptor.fragmentFunction = library.makeFunction(name: "fragment_image_display")

displayImagePipelineState = try! device.makeRenderPipelineState(descriptor: imageDisplayStateDescriptor)
```

There is an error at the creation of the pipeline state:

> fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error
>   Domain=CompilerError Code=1 "Link failed: fragment input vPos **was not**
>   **found in vertex shader outputs**" [...]

I checked and rechecked the code and can't understand what's wrong.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try replacing `stage_in` with `position`. I think that `stage_in` is mostly used with `struct`s where each field is either annotated with a specific attribute qualifier or matched by name. Apparently, when it's used with a non-struct type, it's trying to match by name. For example, if your vertex function were to output a struct one of whose fields was `vPos`, that would find it.

Comment: Isn't the position label used to get the position on the screen rather than the one relative to the rectangle ?

Comment: thank you for your answer, I'll check that tomorrow 

Comment: It's "window-relative", but that really means relative to the viewport, which specifies a portion of the color or depth attachment(s). For a vertex shader like yours, which just returns a `float4`, the return value is the `position`. Since that's what you want as input to your fragment function, you want to annotate that input as `position`, too.